# [LWC]modal in child component backdrop issue

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm facing a modal back-drop issue, here is my code:

in parent component:

```
<c-approve-buttons record-id={recordId}></c-approve-buttons>
```

child component (approveButtons):

```
<section role="dialog" tabindex="-1"
class="slds-modal slds-modal_small slds-fade-in-open">
<div class="slds-modal__container">
<!-- modal contents -->
</div>
</section>
<div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
```

and if I show the child component's modal, it only backdrop the parent element's area:
[image]

I guess it's because the modal's parent Node is the parent component, due to the Shadow DOM, i'm not able to make the child component's parent node to be document. Is it possible, to make backdrop and modal body inside child component show properly?